# Is there a way to render plain HTML from react components without the markup?

Tags: reactjs, chai

I'm writing unit tests for some React components using the handy renderIntoDocument() method, but when I look at the DOM's innerHTML, I'm getting the following:

```
<h3>
  <!-- react-text: 17 -->Start with <!-- /react-text -->
  <span class="theme-secondary-color"><!-- react-text: 19 -->5<!-- /react-text -->
  <!-- react-text: 20 --> Plans<!-- /react-text --></span>
</h3>
```

When I really would like to parse:

```
<h3>
  Start with <span class="theme-secondary-color">5 Plans
  </span>
</h3>
```

I realize that React needs the markup to do it's thing, but is there a utility to strip out the React markup in order to write tests that are easier to read?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup

Comment: Thanks @pawel, works great!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use ReactDOMServer.renderToString() or any other way to render a react component to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110293/should-i-use-reactdomserver-rendertostring-or-any-other-way-to-render-a-react)